# TabNavigator not showing children

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a TabNavigator component which is not showing its children when adding them at runtime.

Is there a way around this please?

I'm doing the following at the moment:

```
var tabNavigator:TabNavigator = new TabNavigator();

// etc.

parentHBoxContainer.addChild(tabNavigator);

 // etc.

// Custom component with nothing special in it

// Trigger on a button click (Add)
var myComponent:MyComponent = new MyComponent();

var nextTabIndex:int = tabNavigator.getChildren().length;
tabNavigator.addChild(myComponent);

// I see some text flashing but the current tab stays the same
// No text is added
tabNavigator.validateNow(); 

tabNavigator.selectedIndex = nextTabIndex;
```

Sorry guys for not giving enough details. The tabNavigator is inside an *HBox* container, I didn't add the code because I thought it would be irrelevant.

I replaced *SimpleComponent* by *MyComponent* in the code above. *MyComponent* is just another *HBox* with a textfield and a label.

Thanks.

Comment: With the current code snippet, the tab navigator is never added as a parent of it's component. I'm unsure if that is a side effect of where you copy and pasted or a problem w/ the actual code.  If you could provide full code that we could run; it would be beneficial.

Comment: Is SimpleComponent a Spark component. Spark components cannot be added to TabNavigator children without some Halo container wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this:

```
tabNavigator.addChild(myComponent);

tabNavigator.selectedChild = myComponent;
```

instead of this:

```
var nextTabIndex:int = tabNavigator.getChildren().length;
tabNavigator.addChild(myComponent);

// I see some text flashing but the current tab stays the same
// No text is added
tabNavigator.validateNow(); 

tabNavigator.selectedIndex = nextTabIndex;
```